# API searchCriteria not working with "FROM and TO" for "created_at" field, fetching the wrong results

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, search-criteria

Im trying to get data for orders that created between 2 dates(2023-10-05 - 2023-10-01).
Im using the search condition type FROM and TO but its not fetching the right details.
This is what im trying:

```
rest/default/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2023-10-01&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=from&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]=2023-10-05&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][conditionType]=to
```

im getting all orders from the website with no filter.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get data for orders that were created between 2 dates(2023-10-05 - 2023-10-01) you can use below endpoints

- **Request :**

> {{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2023-10-01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2023-10-05&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=lteq

- replace **{{base_url}}** with you domain url
- set **admin token** as a bearer token

for more details, you can read this https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/performing-searches/#simple-search-using-a-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "default" from endpoint URL. Something like this "rest/V1/orders?...". If you do not have multi store, it will pull from default store anyway.